# Linked list C implementation

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm reading a data structure and algorithm book in C.  I have implemented a generic single linked list in the C programming language, and I want to know your opinion on my implementation:

***linked_list.h***

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED

#define list_size(list) (list->size)    

#define list_head(list) (list->head)    
#define list_tail(list) (list->tail)
#define list_is_head(list, element) (element == list_head(list))
#define list_is_tail(list, element) (element == list_tail(list))

#define list_append(list, data)     list_ins_next(list, list->tail, data)
#define list_preprend(list, data)   list_ins_next(list, NULL, data)

#define list_data(element)  (element->data)
#define list_next(element)  (element->nextElmt)

typedef struct ListElmt_{
    void *data;
    struct ListElmt_ *nextElmt;
} ListElmt;

typedef struct List_{
    ListElmt *head;
    ListElmt *tail;
    size_t size;    
    void (*destroy)(void *data);
    int (*cmp)(const void *fdata,const void *sdata);
}List;


List *list_init(void (*destroy)(void *data), 
        int (*cmp)(const void *fdata, const void *sdata));
void list_destroy(List *list);
int list_ins_off(List *list, size_t off, void *data); 
int list_ins_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void *data); 
int list_drem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element);
int list_rem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void ** data);
ListElmt * list_find(List *list, void *data, ListElmt *sElmt);

#endif
```

***linked_list.c***

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "linked_list.h" 


List * list_init(void (*destroy)(void *data),
        int (*cmp)(const void *fdata, const void *data)) 
{   
    List *rlist;

    if((rlist = malloc(sizeof *rlist)) != NULL) { 
        rlist->head = NULL; 
        rlist->tail = NULL; 
        rlist->size = 0; 
        rlist->destroy = destroy; 
        rlist->cmp = cmp;
    }

    return rlist;
} 

void list_destroy(List *list) {

    ListElmt * el;
    void *data;

    while( (el=list_head(list)) != NULL) {
        list_rem_next(list, NULL, &data);
        list->destroy(data);
    }

    free(list);
}

int list_ins_next(List *list, ListElmt *elmt, void *data) {

    ListElmt *addElmt = malloc(sizeof *addElmt);
    if(addElmt == NULL)
        return -1;

    addElmt->data = data;

    if(elmt == NULL) {
        addElmt->nextElmt = list->head;
        elmt = list->head = addElmt; // using elmt for checking list tail
    }
    else {
        addElmt->nextElmt = elmt->nextElmt;
        elmt->nextElmt = addElmt;
    }

    // updating list->tail if needed
    if(elmt == list->tail)
        list->tail = addElmt;

    list->size++;

    return 0;
}

int list_ins_off(List *list, size_t off, void *data) {
    if(off < 0 || off >= list->size)
        return list_append(list, data);

    size_t i;
    ListElmt *elmt = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < off; ++i)
        elmt = elmt->nextElmt;

    list_ins_next(list, elmt, data);
    return 0;
}

int list_drem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element) {
    void *data;
    int ret = list_rem_next(list, element, &data);

    if(ret != 0)
        return ret;

    list->destroy(data);
    return 0;
}

int list_rem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void **data) {
    ListElmt *remElmt;

    // the list still not contain any element
    if(list->size == 0 || element->nextElmt == NULL) 
        return -1;

    *data = element->nextElmt->data;
    remElmt = element->nextElmt;

    element->nextElmt = element->nextElmt->nextElmt;

    if(remElmt == list->tail)
        list->tail = element;

    free(remElmt);
    list->size--;

    return 0;
}

ListElmt * find(List *list, void *data, ListElmt *sElmt) {
    if(list->size == 0 || list->cmp == NULL)    
        return NULL;

    sElmt = sElmt ? sElmt : list_head(list);    

    while(sElmt && list->cmp(sElmt->data, data))
        sElmt = sElmt->nextElmt;

    return sElmt;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In order of appearance:

- **list_init**

  While `destroy` is definitely a property of the list, `cmp` is not; it is a property of a particular searc. Only `find` really cares of how to compare elements. It is better to pass a comparator to `find` directly.
- **list_desroy**

  may and should take advantage of knowing the list size. If perchance the list is corrupted, it is possible that the `(el=list_head(list)) != NULL` condition is never satisfied, and the loop becomes infinite. Counting iterations gives you an ability to fail gracefully.
- **Insertions**

  Naming is questionable. `list_ins_next` should be `list_insert_after`; `list_ins_off` should be `list_insert_at`. In any case, do not abbreviate `insert`.
- **Removals**

  The purpose of `list_drem_next` is quite unclear. Why to destroy data of the *next* element? It is much more straightforward to destroy data of *this* element. In any case, you must nullify the data pointer once data are destroyed.

  The name itself is also questionable. `list_destroy_data` sounds better.
- **Missing functionality**

  There is no way to remove the head element.

Answer (score 3):

1. <strike>Your `list_init` contains a rather nasty bug: If `malloc` fails it will return `rList` unitialized which means the caller won't know that the list wasn't properly initialized and gets a pointer into lala land. If he is lucky it will crash the program if not it will start overwriting random memory which can lead to very hard to to debug crashes in totally unrelated and perfectly fine code. Granted if `malloc` fails then there is a good chance your program will die anyway but you should not return uninitialized variables (your compiler should actually warn you about this). If `malloc` fails either return NULL or `abort()`.</strike>
2. Your naming of variables and methods is a little bit terse and/or unconventional.

   - It won't hurt to properly name things. Abbreviating things like `ins`, `drem` etc. do not help readability.
   - `ListElmt` is typically called `Node` or `ListNode`. At least name it `ListElement` - again avoid abbreviations in type names. Modern IDEs do a pretty good job of code completion and any modern compiler can easily deal with the few extra characters.
3. The biggest issue is your interface. The header file should be the public interface to your data structure - anything which is private (helpers etc.) should not be in there.

   - You have defined all your operations to operate on a list - this is perfectly fine. This also means that your should consider using an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) hiding the implementation details from the user of your structure. The advantage is that you can change implementation details without worrying about breaking any existing code which might rely on some internals.
   - Your set of operations seem a bit strange. For example you have a method which finds an element and returns the pointer to it but you only have methods to remove the next element to the one you point to. So how do you find and element and delete it?
4. There is a bunch of helper macros defined (like `list_head`, `list_tail`, etc.) which you sometimes use sometimes not. This is inconsistent. If they are meant for the user of the list then see the point above: the user should not know about these kind of internals anyway.

Comment: ok thanks you, 1) if malloc fail it will return NULL that will be assigned to rlist anyway. 2)where can i put my helper so that there are hidden from the public interface??

Comment: @karim, good point, missed the `=`. You can simply move the method prototype into the `.c` file and mark the implementation `static` so it's not visible outside the `.c` file.

Answer (score 3):

Personal suggestion: I don't really like using macros unless I have to, so I would
suggest using [inline functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#Comparison_with_macros) for the short one-liner list methods that are currently 
implemented as macros. The main advantages would be actual type checking and better compiler error messages if you make a mistake when writing the code.

---

The function pointers `cmp` and `destroy` appear in a couple different places. 
It is a good idea to replace those with typedefs to avoid a typo in any of the repeated
declarations and to simplify maintenance if you ever need to change the function signature:

```
typedef void (*func_destroy) (void *data);
typedef int  (*func_compare) (const void *fdata, const void *sdata);
```

---

Integer return codes are pretty old school, in my opinion. Returning `0` on success and `-1`
on error is an invitation to confusion. A programmer that didn't bother reading the documentation
or looking at the source code might just assume it is returning a boolean 0|1 value
and call your function like this:

```
if ( list_rem_next(...) )
{
    // nice, it worked
}
```

And never realize that the `if` statement would not be executed at any point.

A better interface, in the simple case of a list, would be including [`<stdbool.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdbool/) and
changing the return value of the functions to `bool`, returning `true` on success and `false` on error.

---

It is a good practice when using pointers to always validate them before accessing the
pointed contents. You should at least [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) in every function that the `list` pointers
and others are not `NULL`.